environment avariable automatically changed after shuffling a column in a datatable
I'm running some code with data table in R studio. Here samples is a list of datatable, id is the index of some datatable in the list. I want to create a copy of samples[[id]], so I first do sa = samples[[id]], and I want to shuffle the 'type' column in sa, so I do
sa[, type := sample(sa$type)]
sa = samples[[id]]
sa[, type := sample(sa$type)]

However, after I ran the two lines of code, I did not touch 'samples' at all, but the value in samples automatically changed, like the 'type' column of samples[[id]] is also randomly shuffled.
I'm very confused why this happens, cause I never touch samples.
I did some experiments, if I do
sa = samples[[id]]
sa$type = sample(sa$type)
sa[, type := sample(sa$type)]

which actually shuffled twice, then the 'samples' are safe and will not change.
Does anyone have some clues about this? I mean, 'samples' somehow changed automatically!

I imagine you're hitting this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225098/understanding-exactly-when-a-data-table-is-a-reference-to-vs-a-copy-of-another - as maybe more clearly shown here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51756125/data-table-update-by-reference-changes-other-data-table

@thelatemail THANKS so much! This is exactly what I'm looking for and searching for a long time. Good to know and understand the reference semantics of datatable!!!! SUPER appreciate your help!
